# EasyOCR isn't adding proper linebreaks to the extracted text

Tags: python, ocr, easyocr

Here's the gist of the code:

```
import fitz
import easyocr
from PIL import Image

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], download_enabled=False)
    extracted_text = ""
    for page_number in range(pdf_document.page_count):
    
        page = pdf_document[page_number]
        resolution = 300
        zoomfactor = resolution/72.0
        pixmap = page.get_pixmap(matrix-fitz.Matrix(zoomfactor, zoomfactor))
        image = pixmap.tobytes()
        result = reader.readtext(image, paragraph=True)

        print("Page {page_number + 1} - OCR Result:") 
        for detection in result:
            extracted_text += detection[1]

    pdf_document.close()
    
return extracted_text
```

The image passed looks something like this:

[image]

But the extracted text looks like this:
"account: 1234url: xyz"

The expectation is:

"account: 1234

url: xyz"

It seems like easyOCR is extracting each word separately and not reading the image line by line. Probably because there's a huge space between the words on a single line.

Can you please suggest something?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.jaided.ai/easyocr/documentation/) you can specify Bounding Box Merging (_y_ths (float, default = 0.5) - Maximum verticall distance to merge text boxes when paragraph=True._). I would assume that you need to adjust this setting.

Comment: @MarkusSafar x_ths did the trick! I set x_ths to 1000.0 so that it should take everything on a single horizontal line as one string.

Comment: Great to hear, glad I could help 

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.jaided.ai/easyocr/documentation/) you can specify Bounding Box Merging.

> x_ths (float, default = 1.0) - Maximum horizontal distance to merge text boxes when paragraph=True.
> y_ths (float, default = 0.5) - Maximum verticall distance to merge text boxes when paragraph=True.

Modifying one of these should do the trick

Update:
According to the op, setting `x_ths` to 1000.0 did solve the issue.

Comment: If you want to handle command arguments use `System.CommandLine` or one of the many commandline parsers. The question you posted made little sense and always exited silently unless there were less than 2 arguments

Comment: Dear @PanagiotisKanavos: I'm very sorry but I cannot relate your comment with the answer I have posted. Can you please clarify what you mean? What question are you referring to?

Comment: The one that got closed and downvoted yesterday because it was unclear.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It seems I haven't slept enough because I still don't get it. I have only posted one question here and that was not yesterday but on 7th of July in 2014. Is it possible that you are mistaking me with someone else?